# How to enable php extension using SaltStack

Tags: php, vagrant, salt-stack

I'm using SaltStack to provision my Vagrant VM. I've installed php fine, but I need to enable the intl extension. I'm pretty sure that it is installed but I can't work out how I can get salt to enable it for me. Is there a way I can get it to create a php.ini or something like that?

Here's my php55.sls file:

```
php55:
    pkg:
        - installed
        - pkgs:
            - php55
            - php55-apcu
            - php55-mod-php
            - libjpeg-turbo8
```

and my top.sls:

```
base:
  '*':
    - apache2-mpm-prefork
    - php55
    - mysql
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how I install a module using PECL and enable it. The last state is what you want, but I paste the full example to clarify.

```
php-mongo-builddeps:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - php-devel
      - glibc-devel
      - gcc
      - php-phpunit-PHPUnit
      - php-bcmath

mongo-php-reqs:
  pecl.installed:
    - name: mongo
    - require:
      - pkg: php-pkgs
      - pkg: php-mongo-builddeps

php-enable-extension:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/php.d/mongo.ini
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
    - contents: 'extension=mongo.so'
    - watch_in:
      - service: httpd
```

Comment: How would I use "pecl.installed" to install an already downloaded file? In case the minion has no internet access.

Answer (score 1):

I was googling for a better solution, when i stumbled upon your question. I don't think it's perfect, but i prefer enabling it per `cli` vs managing a file, like diegows suggests.

```
php7.0:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - php7.0-cli

install xdebug:
  pecl.installed:
    - name: xdebug
    - require:
      - pkg: php7.0
  cmd.run:
    - name: phpenmod xdebug
    - require:
      - pecl: install xdebug
```

ps. for php 5.x, use `php5enmod`, instead of `phpenmod`